# My await syntax is not working properly

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

As you can see in the code below, first i am asking the user to turn on the location then i get the geolocation of the user. I should only go towards if the user accept or decline the location permission.

THis way the answer is undefinied and i get to the "answer is no or undefinied" console log part. I need to wait for the answer, if i get the answer continue in the code.

```
     async locationReq() {
    this.locationAccuracy.canRequest().then((canRequest: boolean) => {

      if (canRequest) {
        this.locationAccuracy.request(this.locationAccuracy.REQUEST_PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY).then(
          (success) => {
            if (success.message == this.locationAccuracy.SUCCESS_USER_AGREED || success.message==this.locationAccuracy.ERROR_USER_DISAGREED) {
              this.answer=true;
            }
            else{
              this.answer=false;
              alert("Hiba történt. Kérlek próbáld újra!");
            }

          });
      }

      console.log(this.answer);
    }).then(() => {

      if (this.answer == true) {
        console.log("answer is true");
        this.plt.ready().then(() => {
          let loader = this.loadingCtrl.create({
            content: "Helyadatok lekérdezése..."
          });
          loader.present();
          var options = {
            timeout: 15000
          };

          this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(options).then(resp => {
            this.lat = resp.coords.latitude;
            this.lang = resp.coords.longitude;
            loader.dismiss();
            this.mapLoadingPresent();
          }).catch(() => {
            this.lat = 47.49801;
            this.lang = 19.03991;
            loader.dismiss();
            this.mapLoadingPresent();
            this.presentToast();
          });

        })
      } else {
        console.log("answer is no or undefinied");
      }
    });

  }
```

Comment: You say `this.locationAccuracy.canRequest()` and `this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(options)` are running simultaneously. What makes you think so?

Comment: you can see that my timeout option is in the plt.ready. So the timeout should not even start until the canRequest is finished.

Comment: What makes you think is starts before canRequest is finished?

Comment: You ask about a timeout starts too early, but you've posted an incomplete code which doesn't even have the timeout. Mind providing a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: updated the code and description.

Comment: There is no `await` in the edited code, despite the title asks about "await syntax". I guess using async/await is irrelevant. Consider isolating the problem.

Comment: It seems `this.answer` is `undefined` because `.canRequest()` returns `false`.

Answer (score 0):

I've refactored your code to make use of the `async/await` syntax. In any `this.answer` seems to be `undefined` because the `canRequest()` call returned `false`

```
const canRequest = await this.locationAccuracy.canRequest();

if (canRequest) {
  const success = await this.locationAccuracy.request(this.locationAccuracy.REQUEST_PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);

  if (success.message == this.locationAccuracy.SUCCESS_USER_AGREED || success.message == this.locationAccuracy.ERROR_USER_DISAGREED) {
    this.answer = true;
  } else {
    this.answer = false;
    alert('Hiba történt. Kérlek próbáld újra!');
  }
}

// If `this.answer` is undefined  it means `canRequest()` returned `false`
// otherwise it will be `true` or `false`
console.log(this.answer);

if (this.answer == true) {
  console.log('answer is true');
  await this.plt.ready();

  const loader = this.loadingCtrl.create({ content: 'Helyadatok lekérdezése...' });
  loader.present(); // Not sure if this must be awaited..

  const options = { timeout: 15000 };

  try {
    const resp = await this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(options);
    this.lat = resp.coords.latitude;
    this.lang = resp.coords.longitude;
  } catch (err) {
    this.lat = 47.49801;
    this.lang = 19.03991;
    this.presentToast(); // Not sure if this must be awaited..
  } finally {
    loader.dismiss(); // Not sure if this must be awaited..
    this.mapLoadingPresent(); // Not sure if this must be awaited..
  }
} else {
  console.log('answer is no or undefinied');
}
```